# iTunes Sever on Synology NAS and Apple Music

Tags: itunes, catalina, music, nas

I have a Synology NAS that's running an iTunes server.  It was setup by my brother and it works. I can share this library with my different Macs around the house (do the models matter)?  Anyway, I would use iTunes to play the music from the server.  Now that I've upgraded to Catalina, I can't get Apple Music to do connect anymore.

How can I get Apple Music to see my iTunes server so I can play music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current release version of the iTunes server for Synology is not compatible with Catalina. If you register a ticket with Synology outlining your problem, they will send you an updated server spk to install.

Having said that, there is still a problem which I'm having and I've not been able to find out so far if it's just me or not. The problem I'm seeing is that albums with multiple artists are being listed in the albums list multiple times. once per artist. A real pain for collections.